# ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for null

Tags: binding, null, cxf, factory, bus

I am using cxf webservice client in java. My code runs all fine in eclipse but when i create a jar and try running from the cmd, i get this error (shown at the end) :-

the org.apache.cxf version i am using is 2.5.3  . Any idea what the reason could be??

> org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for null
>   00:01:11    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:350)
>   00:01:11    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpointInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:258)
>   00:01:11    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:143)
>   00:01:11    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
>   00:01:11    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:155)
>   00:01:11    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:155)
>   00:01:11    at com.cisco.nm.nmtgre.b360.automation.IpCentralFetcher.getProjectAssets(IpCentralFetcher.java:58)
>   00:01:11    at com.cisco.nm.nmtgre.b360.automation.IpCentralParser.getIpCentralByProjectVersionId(IpCentralParser.java:122)
>   00:01:11    at com.cisco.nm.nmtgre.b360.automation.IpCentralParser.getIPcFromXml(IpCentralParser.java:51)
>   00:01:11    at com.cisco.nm.nmtgre.b360.automation.IpCentralParser.main(IpCentralParser.java:245)
>   00:01:11 Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No binding factory for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/ registered.
>   00:01:11    at org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManagerImpl.getBindingFactory(BindingFactoryManagerImpl.java:120)
>   00:01:11    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:338)
>   00:01:11    ... 9 more

Comment: How are you generating jar file? Where are dependency jar files?  in the classpath or creaate a single jar with dependency?

Comment: It looks like you don't put enough CXF related jars in your class path.